# What's the the memory eviction strategy of Spark? FIFO or LRU?

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management

I tried to figure out the memory eviction strategy of Spark that they say it's LRU ([here](https://0x0fff.com/spark-misconceptions/) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14289)).

However, when I looked into the source code of [MemoryStore](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/memory/MemoryStore.scala) and [BlockManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManager.scala), I can't find the logic of LRU:

1. There is a LinkedHashMap recording all the blocks in the MemoryStore

   ```
   // Note: all changes to memory allocations, notably putting blocks, evicting blocks, and
   // acquiring or releasing unroll memory, must be synchronized on `memoryManager`!
   private val entries = new LinkedHashMap[BlockId, MemoryEntry[_]](32, 0.75f, true)
   ```
2. when a block is visited, it will not be moved to the head of the LinkedHashMap

   ```
   def getValues(blockId: BlockId): Option[Iterator[_]] = {
       val entry = entries.synchronized { entries.get(blockId) }
       entry match {
           case null => None
           case e: SerializedMemoryEntry[_] =>
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("should only call getValues on deserialized blocks")
           case DeserializedMemoryEntry(values, _, _) =>
           val x = Some(values)
           x.map(_.iterator)
       }
   }
   ```
3. in the logic of evicting blocks, the selected blocks are in the order of LinkedHashMap's entrySet,
   which I think is First-In-and-First-Out

   ```
   private[spark] def evictBlocksToFreeSpace(
        blockId: Option[BlockId],
        space: Long,
        memoryMode: MemoryMode): Long = {
      assert(space > 0)
      memoryManager.synchronized {
        var freedMemory = 0L
        val rddToAdd = blockId.flatMap(getRddId)
        val selectedBlocks = new ArrayBuffer[BlockId]
        def blockIsEvictable(blockId: BlockId, entry: MemoryEntry[_]): Boolean = {
          entry.memoryMode == memoryMode && (rddToAdd.isEmpty || rddToAdd != getRddId(blockId))
        }
        // This is synchronized to ensure that the set of entries is not changed
        // (because of getValue or getBytes) while traversing the iterator, as that
        // can lead to exceptions.
        entries.synchronized {
          val iterator = entries.entrySet().iterator()
          while (freedMemory < space && iterator.hasNext) {
            val pair = iterator.next()
            val blockId = pair.getKey
            val entry = pair.getValue
            if (blockIsEvictable(blockId, entry)) {
              // We don't want to evict blocks which are currently being read, so we need to obtain
              // an exclusive write lock on blocks which are candidates for eviction. We perform a
              // non-blocking "tryLock" here in order to ignore blocks which are locked for reading:
              if (blockInfoManager.lockForWriting(blockId, blocking = false).isDefined) {
                selectedBlocks += blockId
                freedMemory += pair.getValue.size
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ...
        if (freedMemory >= space) {
          logInfo(s"${selectedBlocks.size} blocks selected for dropping " +
            s"(${Utils.bytesToString(freedMemory)} bytes)")
          for (blockId <- selectedBlocks) {
            val entry = entries.synchronized { entries.get(blockId) }
            // This should never be null as only one task should be dropping
            // blocks and removing entries. However the check is still here for
            // future safety.
            if (entry != null) {
              dropBlock(blockId, entry)
            }
          }
         ...
        }
      }
    }
   ```

So, the eviction strategy of Spark is FIFO or LRU?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `LinkedHashMap` you have in this line:

```
private val entries = new LinkedHashMap[BlockId, MemoryEntry[_]](32, 0.75f, true)
```

is a constructor to create an **access order** in `LinkedHashMap`:

```
LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder)
```

`accessOrder` flag is `true` which simply says that the keys are sorted on the basis of access order from least recently accessed used to most recently accessed.

In other words, the eviction strategy is LRU. The blocks are sorted based on their access order in the entries `LinkedHashMap`. The selected blocks for eviction are in the order of `LinkedHashMap`'s `entrySet`, which means the first block to be evicted is the least recent used block.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question before, but the answer is pretty tricky:
From the code you pasted here, there is no an explicit "promoting" operation.
But in fact, "LinkedHashMap" is a special data structure that will ensure the LRU order.